# DC current for mini fridge

Tags: electrical

Do mini fridges actually run on DC current that is converted from 110 V AC input? I would like to convert one to DC so I can use it in a camper van.

Comment: It depends.  What’s the make and model number?

Comment: Will this camper van ever *move*? I ask because they make mini-fridges specifically for RV/camper use, and they run on 120V, 12V or sometimes even natural gas(!). These are built tough to survive the stress and vibration of a moving vehicle.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement.  You can take the tour at https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour to learn about this SE.  I agree with Tyson that you will want more specific information about your individual fridge.  Without knowing that I cannot give you an authoritative answer.  Just because it is a mini-fridge does not mean that it has any 12 Volt parts inside.  It would seem more cost-effective to have a motor that runs directly on 120 V.

Comment: A designed-for-120VAC compressor motor will almost certainly not work with 12VDC.

Comment: @DanielGriscom they do make mini-fridges tho that really are 12V DC, with a 120v plug and transformer. My dorm room fridge when I was a college freshman was configured exactly that way...

Comment: @Tyson ... and this was for a fridge that wasn't promoted as being 12VDC-compatible? Seems unlikely; AC motors are usually cheaper and more reliable (no brushes) than DC motors.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I couldn’t tell you how it was marketed, but my guess would be it was sold as dual voltage.  I never owned it, I rented it from a company in business to rent thing to students.  The cord had a locking connector close to the fridge, followed by a power brick and 120v plug.  The rental didn’t come with the 12v pigtail that I would imagine came with it new in-box.  OP here has probably seen something similar.

Comment: Like this (only mine was bigger): https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07B94NGN8/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_.UTWAbXY9VRCX there’s actually quite a few on amazon.. I just searched.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Just an FYI there are many types of DC Motors that do not use brushes for example BLDC Brushless DC Motor, DC Servo motors (similar to BLDC) and DC Stepper motors just to name a few.

Comment: @Ken ... but are any of these cheap, powerful, and likely to be used in a refrigerator?

Comment: The biggest problem you have with a fridge is the motor is not an *a la carte* boltable item. Why? There's freon. Given a choice between having a rotating shaft cross the freon seal, or having *wires* cross the freon seal, they choose the latter for reliability.   Like an A/C window unit, **the motor is enveloped entirely inside the freon**. You can't change it.  The freon envelope is entirely welded and nonserviceable

Comment: little DC ones without compressors (peltier) are _ok_ to keep things cool, but they can only keep up with the outside (usually), so they can't freeze something like game, but if you load with cold pop+milk and stuff, it should keep them cold. you can add ice with hot items to maintain a balance, removing the water later.

Comment: @DanielGriscom yes there are some of them power clothes washers. However as Harper has stated the compressor in a fridge is hermetically sealed - motor, compressor and oil all sealed up. So changing a motor is not that simple ..

Answer (score 3):

### Not so easy

The first thing you must learn is that you can't "dip" a vehicle battery very far, *least of all your starting battery*.  With lead-acid batteries, you can't use more than about 25% of its charge on a daily basis or you will degrade the battery and have short life.

Lithium batteries are much better (and more expensive) and you can use most of their range daily, but even really good Apple quality ones are only good for about 1000 full cycles.

### Peltier fridges - too inefficient

A few "mini-fridges" operate on the Peltier principle using solid-state. This *seems* cool until you realize how ghastly inefficient they are. They do indeed operate internally on 12 voltish DC (with an AC adapter) but are *rather weak* and can only keep things cool, not chill them.  Far worse, their poor efficiency will necessitate a much larger battery.

### House fridges can't handle vibration or shock

The #1 problem with residential grade refrigerators is they are **not built for the vibration and shocks of being in a vehicle**. Motion will tear them apart.  That's why they're out.

Just informationally...

These machines use the normal freon-compressor cycle, which is efficient.  However they are AC-only and have a big AC draw when they start.  That requires **a big inverter to drive them**.  What's more, they don't run very often, but you don't know *when*, so you must run the big inverter 24x7.  A large inverter driving no load has a **high "standby" energy cost**, which saps your battery.

"Other than that, Mrs. Lincoln"... people building alternative-power homes love the common residential-grade fridge.  They used to make very special fridges for solar off-grid use, with 6" thick walls - but it turns out there's no need, since recent Energy Star refrigerators are *so good*.  This presumes you already have a nice large inverter already in place for other reasons... and the battery bank to drive it.

### Ammonia (propane) refrigerators

Some refrigerators work in a triple mode:  120V, 12V or propane.  These work on a less efficient ammonia cycle - great on propane, weak on 12V.  It also introduces the risk of a propane leak into your RV, which can kill  you explosively.

### Freon refrigerators made for RVs

This is the best of all worlds.  The machine is sturdy enough to bounce around.  It uses the efficient Freon cycle.  It is either 12V or multi-voltage -- either using a DC motor internally, or a "brushless DC" (read: an AC motor driven by its own onboard inverter  that only runs when the motor is in use, so no standby losses).

The best fridges actually open *from the top* - after all if you've ever been hit by a curtain of cold air when you open a vertical fridge, you know cold air wants to go down.  Fridges/freezers with top lids don't lose much cold when you open them.

How do I know so much?  I follow people on the Internet who put refrigerators in vehicles.  You can too; look at

- British narrowboating (also called "on the cut", cut being a civil engineering term)
- Boaters generally, but beware, boats don't hit potholes
- #VanLife - the US "people who turn vans and delivery trucks into stealth RVs
- Off-grid* folks using solar/wind power to homestead, they use 12V fridges, most of which are vehicle-rated

---

* In the "I don't have a mains electrical feed" sense of the term, heh heh

Comment: Great details here, and thanks for the mention of how to find more information.  Been thinking about RVs so interesting to know more about the fridges in them.

Answer (score 2):

RV or camper refrigerators are an ammonia evap system. That's how the can run on gas. A gas flame or electric heater heats the ammonia and as it rises and condensates it removes the heat from the air causing the unit to cool. The small mini fridges use a compressor and refrigerant for cooling and uses quite a bit more power to cool. That would be a large drain on a battery even if connected to an inverter. That's why they are not used in a camper.

Comment: The part about being an impracticable drain on a battery is no longer true.  Fridge efficiency is way up of late, particularly top-door fridges that keep the cold when you open them.  Read up any of the narrowboating or #vanlife blogs or channels that talk about having fridges.